# Multiple XIBs in tableView

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell1") as! TableViewCell1
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell2") as! TableViewCell2
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell3") as! TableViewCell3
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell4") as! TableViewCell4
        return cell        }
}
```

But I still need a default return value and I don't know what it should be.

I have registered the xibs in view did load. Right now they just display a different solid color background

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tablecell1")
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tablecell2")
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell3", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tablecell3")
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell4", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tablecell4")
}
```

Comment: `return UITableViewCell()` ?

Comment: I am doing something wrong, the tableView is empty. It should only show 4 rows with different colored cells.

Comment: `UITableView` will always generate enough cells to cover the entire screen (or at least its height)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to sent default value in all the methods which are returning something, Here `cellForRowAtIndexpath` returns `UITableviewcelll` so you must have to provide default value.

**One trick you can use is:**

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell1") as! TableViewCell1
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell2") as! TableViewCell2
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell3") as! TableViewCell3
        return cell
    } else { // This will be your index 3
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell4") as! TableViewCell4
        return cell      
  }
```

Comment: Here compiler wants "else" case so if all "if" conditions are false then "else" definitely will get executed. In your question all re "if" conditions but you have not specified that what if all "if" are false